# plantUML: swimlanes, overlapping connectors with flow continuation from 2 to 1

Tags: plantuml, activity-diagram

I'm taking this Q/A as a basis:
[plantUML: swimlanes and overlapping connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020100/plantuml-swimlanes-and-overlapping-connectors/75579959)

The peculiarity there is that the action flow comes to an end in p1 and P2, the two boxes are *detached*.
What can be done if the flow continues, specifically where the two boxes lead to only one follow-up?

Just removing the *detach *won't work. What I actually want is the red arrow to be produced rather than the one from 3010 to 3006.

**PlantUML diagram**:

[image: PlantUML diagram]

That's the code as taken from the other post, just with re-ordered swimlanes (if sb knows how to fix the overlap of the arrow through the green box, that would also be welcome).

```
@startuml

title something

|#daf0fe|Backend|
|#dee4e8|p1|
|#c4c9cd|p2|

|Backend|
start
    :something;
    if (open) then (yes)
        :generate open data;
        split
            #3f3:Mail to p1\nMAIL ID: **3010**|
            |p1|
            :Receive Mail **3010**;
        split again
            |Backend|
            #3f3:Mail to p2\nMAIL ID: **3006**|
        end split
        |p2|
        :Receive Mail **3006**;
    endif
    |Backend|
    #HotPink:something else>
stop
@enduml
```

Tried to add another *split* hierarchy, but that wouldn't work. Neither would *goto*.

Comment: I think the red arrow you'd like to have is not consistent with the split syntax, at least not in PlantUML. Those are parallel flows and so, the flow control must `join` (end split) before you can terminate the condition.

Comment: Splits across swimlanes are troublesome in PlantUML. In your example, I don't think it's useful to show p1/p2, since I don't think the backend would block on them receiving the mail (the point of sending mail is that it's asynchronous). The way the example is done, it implies that the backend will wait (block) until both p1 and p2 have received their mails.

Comment: I only used this example to have a reference. The technical correctness is not relevant here since my use case is completely different and has nothing to do with email (it's about a process description with roles in a swimlane, boxes as processes respectively artifacts as inputs and outputs)

Comment: If the arrow as suggested is not possible because the syntax does not allow it, then I have the information I wanted (not the one I had hoped for though ;), and it seems I have to look for another tool.